# dynamic debug statement of kernel in which file

Tags: debugging, linux-kernel, kernel, linux-device-driver, kernel-module

I have enabled the CONFIG_DYNAMIC_DEBUG option in kernel. After which we get control file in debug/dynamic_debug directory.

After we enable some debug logs in control file, where this log statements will be printed, in which log file ?

Comment: Are the not in kernel log? `dmesg`

Comment: debug logs are not coming in dmesg

Comment: Have you read documentation on this feature ([Documentation/dynamic-debug-howto.txt](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/Documentation/dynamic-debug-howto.txt))? Isn't its section `Viewing Dynamic Debug Behaviour` sufficient for you?

Answer (score 2):

You can check kernel log level by `cat /proc/sys/kernel/printk`. Default is 4. Log levels are defined here https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/include/linux/kern_levels.h?id=refs/tags/v4.8-rc8#n7. As a test you can set it to highest to make sure that everything is logged: `echo "7" > /proc/sys/kernel/printk`.

You can also run `cat /proc/kmsg` while the dynamic debug statements are running. It /proc/kmsg holds kernel messages for them to be picked up by dmesg or something else.